# MySQL Sorting using order by not working using unio

Tags: mysql, sorting, union

I'm using an union statement in mysql but i've some problems sorting the results. The ORDER statement doesn't works at all, the results comes out always sorted by the id field.

Here an example query:

```
SELECT a.* FROM ( ( select * from ticket_ticket AS t1 WHERE ticket_active=1 ORDER BY t1.ticket_date_last_modified DESC ) 
UNION ( select * from ticket_ticket AS t2 WHERE ticket_active=0 ORDER BY t2.ticket_date_last_modified DESC, t2.ticket_status_id DESC ) )
AS a LIMIT 0,20;
```

I want to order the results of the first SELECT by last_modified time, and the second SELECT by time and status. But the ORDER statement get just skipped. The results always come out ordered by the ticket_id ( the PRIMARY KEY ).
What's wrong in this query ?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried putting the order by outside?

Comment: You need to put order by clause on the outer query.

Comment: But i'm using the union becouse i've the need to order the results of the two query in a different way! How can i do that moving the order statement in the outer query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i've fixed it writing the query this way:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM
 (SELECT *
  FROM ticket_ticket
 WHERE ticket_active=1
 ORDER BY ticket_date_last_modified DESC) AS a
UNION ALL
SELECT b.*
FROM
(SELECT *
 FROM ticket_ticket
 WHERE ticket_active=0
 ORDER BY ticket_date_last_modified DESC, ticket_status_id DESC) AS b LIMIT 0,
                                                                          20;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a UNION query that will return distinct values, and the order of the returned rows is not guaranteed.

But you don't need an union query for this:

```
select *
from ticket_ticket AS t1
ORDER BY
  ticket_active!=1,
  ticket_date_last_modified DESC,
  ticket_status_id DESC
LIMIT 0,20;
```